# Rencontres Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm having trouble understanding rencontres numbers, $D_{n,k}$.

The numerical values shown of the wiki page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers

**Looking at n = 3:**

1. $D_{3,3} = 1$ I think I understand this because there is only one way to give all three items to the correct person
2. $D_{3,2} = 0$ because if 2 people had the correct item the third person must also have the right item
3. $D_{3,1} = 3$ as there are three different ways to give one person the right item
4. $D_{3,0} = 2$ this is the part I don't understand, I thought the answer should be 1 as there is only one way to give nobody the right item

Can someone please explain why for $n =3$ and $k=0$ the answer is $2$?

Answer (score 1):

You could give item $1$ to person $2$, item $2$ to person $3$ and item $3$ to person $1$, or item $1$ to person $3$, item $2$ to person $1$ and item $3$ to person $2$.  That's two ways.

Answer (score 1):

If there are three people ($A, B, C$) and three presents ($a, b, c$), there are two ways in which nobody gets the right present.

$$\begin{align*}
&A \;\;\; B \;\;\; C \\\\
&c \;\;\;\; a \;\;\;\; b \\\\
&b \;\;\;\; c \;\;\;\; a \\\\
\end{align*}$$